# Can someone tell me what ActionController::Base.view_paths.each(&:clear_cache) does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know ActionController::Base.view_paths gets me the load paths for the views but the only thing I can finde for clear_cache has to do with the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb#L39-41

The `@cached` variable is modified wherever the `cached` method is called: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb#L70-90

It will clear all cached templates and load them again from disk, by the looks of things.

Comment: So where does this caching happen? what makes it happen? I take it it not your typical Fragment caching?

Comment: Actually found out where the code was coming from its the 2nd solution to the bug in Rails 3.0 described here https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5847-rails-301-configaction_viewcache_template_loading-is-missing.

I just got rid of it and replaced it with config.action_view.cache_template_loading = false since that is supported in Rails 3.1